# How to use neo4j to query an ego network of a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to query an ego network of person-the edges of the nodes which have connections with the node I need to query. Anybody knows that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:{name})-[:FRIEND]-(friend:Person)
MATCH (friend)-[r]-()
RETURN r
```